# Verifying If key or value exists in dictionary, works for char and fails for number

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

Why is below program returns nothing when I provide input `1` or `3`. And works in case of `c`.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

d = {'a':1, 'b':3, 8:'c'}

x = input()
if x in d.values():
        print('In a dictionary')
```

**UPDATE:**
Same for key also if I provide `a` or `b`. It works. For `8`, it returns none.

```
y = input()

if y in d:
        print('key in dictionary')
```

What should I do for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input()` returns a string. Following code might be useful.

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':3, 8:'c'}

x = input()
from string import digits
if x in digits:
    x = int(x)
if x in d.values():
    print('In a dictionary', x)


>>> 
c
In a dictionary c

>>> 
3
In a dictionary 3
```

Similarly, to check in keys, do:

```
d = {'a':1, 'b':3, 8:'c'}

x = input()
from string import digits
if x in digits:
    x = int(x)
if x in d.values():
    print('In a dictionary', x)

if x in d:
    print ("In keys!")
```

Output Test:

```
>>> 
1
In a dictionary 1
>>> 
a
In keys!
```

To convert the keys and values to strings, you can use a dictionary comprehension.

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':3, 8:'c'}
>>> d = {str(x): str(d[x]) for x in d}
>>> d
{'8': 'c', 'a': '1', 'b': '3'}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks great. But I still think I should convert values/keys in dict to string so that I can use them directly.

Comment: To do that you can use a dictionary comprehension, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using Python 3 where `input()` returns a `str`. Use

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval(input())
```

to achieve your desired result (assuming your input is `'c'` (quotation marks included))

eg.

```
>>> import ast
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':3, 8:'c'}
>>> ast.literal_eval(input()) in d.values()
'c'
True
>>> ast.literal_eval(input()) in d.values()
1
True
```

Comment: @Drt This is assuming you are using a Python literal eg. `'c'`, you can't just type `c` since this doesn't magically check which variable type it thinks you have

Comment: @jamylak yes i am using 'c'

Comment: @Drt Yes you used `c` instead of `'c'` just like I said. Look at my console input I use `'c'`, which is equivalent to `ast.literal_eval("'c'")`

Comment: for "'c'" it gives no output. And If I want to use `c`. How can I do that

Comment: @Drt see the other answers for that

Comment: Also the same issue is also for keys in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

First of all, input() returns a string, in your case it would be best to convert the values to strings in order to compare them, since you have mixed value types (which is not recommended)

```
x = input()
```

Secondly, checking if 'x' is 'in' the 'd.values()' might seem like it is fast since 'd.values()' is an iterator, but using 'in' treats it as a list. It would be faster to do this:

```
for v in d.values():
    if x == str(v): # convert v to str
        print('In a dictionary')
        break
else:
    print('NOT In a dictionary')
```

This uses the "for / else" rule, meaning that if the for loop finished iterating over all elements in 'd.values()' without 'breaking' it will trigger 'else'

Comment: For simple, key/value exists or not, this looks like too much hassle. Isn't there any other easy way?