# Creating a dictionary in Python + working with that dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am quite new to Python and am just trying to get my head around some basics.

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to perform the following tasks. I have a text file with multiple lines, those lines are as follows:

```
name1, variable, variable, variable
name2, variable, variable, variable
name3, variable, variable, variable
```

I want to store these items in a dictionary so they can be easily called. I want the name to be the key. I then want to be able to call the variables like this: key[0] or key[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645371/verifying-if-key-or-value-exists-in-dictionary-works-for-char-and-fails-for-num)

The code I have at the moment does not do this:

```
d = {}
with open("servers.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[int(key)] = val
```

Once this is done, I would like to be able to take an input from a user and then check the array to see if this item is present in the array. I have found a few threads on Stackoverflow however none seem to do what I require.

There is a Similar Question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16645371/verifying-if-key-or-value-exists-in-dictionary-works-for-char-and-fails-for-num).

Any assistance you can provide would be amazing. I am new to this but I hope to learn fast & start contributing to threads myself in the near future :)

Cheers!

Comment: Question, not thread. [No tagline please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: If your code is not working, you should describe the current behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there. Assuming that `.split()` actually splits the lines correctly (which it wouldn't do if there are actual commas between the values), you just need an additional unpacking operator (`*`):

```
d = {}
with open("servers.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       key, *val = line.split() # first element -> key, rest -> val[0], val[1] etc.
       d[int(key)] = val
```

If you want to check if a user-entered key exists, you can do something like

```
ukey = int(input("Enter key number: "))
values = d.get(ukey)
if d is not None:
    # do something
else:
    print("That key doesn't exist.")
```

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your first answer! This is great!
I was wondering if you could tell me the answer to my second question regarding asking a user for input and then checking if the key exists?

Comment: Sorry... I think this is only a small isue... So here is my alteration of the code:

d = {}
with open("servers.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       key, *val = line.split()
       d[str(key)] = val



async def say(server, message):
 d.get(server)
 if d is not None:
  await client.say(d[1] + d[2])
 else:
  await client.say(server + " does not exist in your list.")


When I attempt the check of the dictionary I getting a KeyError on the following line: await client.say(d[1] + d[2])

Comment: You need to assign the result of `.get()` to a variable and look up *its* values: `v = d.get(server)`, `if v is not None:` and `await client.say(v[1] + v[2])`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that your file my_file.csv looks like:

```
name1, variable, variable, variable
name2, variable, variable, variable
name3, variable, variable, variable
```

Use pandas to do the work:

```
import pandas as pd

result = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', index_col=0, header=None)
print(result)

print(result.loc['name1'])
```

Notice that pandas is a 3rd party library, and you need to install it using pip or easy_install tools.